# SYS_READ call only works once, seemingly skips over code when ran again

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to rewrite a little text game in assembly for fun, and I noticed that I'm only able to run the following code successfully once. If I run it again elsewhere, it will seemingly skip over the code.

I am compiling using the following command:

`nasm -f elf64 -o test.o textgame.s && ld -o test test.o && ./test`

[Full code](https://hastebin.com/migiketiha.pl)

```
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, buffer
mov rdx, buffer_len
syscall
```

Comment: With a `buffer_len` of `1` there is no place for the linefeed so the next time around that will be read.

Comment: Please don't link to other sides for your code.  Instead, add the code to your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to Jester!

> With a buffer_len of 1 there is no place for the linefeed so the next time around that will be read.